# Check if array contains elements having elements of another array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
$find=array('or','and','not');
$text=array('jasvjasvor','asmasnand','tekjbdkcjbdsnot');
```

I have to check if text array contains any of the elements find has. I'm able to do this for single text but don't know how to do it for all texts

```
$counter=0;  
foreach($find as $txt){
        if (strstr($text[0], $txt)) {
        $counter++;
}
```

If i use this technique i'll have to run foreach number of times. Is there any other way to do this?

NOTE **if array value contains or,and ,not not the whole word match**

http://codepad.viper-7.com/VKBMtP

**Input**

```
$find=array('or','and','not');
$text=array('jasvjasvor','asmasn','tekjbdkcjbdsnot'); 
// array values "jasvjasvor" and "tekjbdkcjbdsnot" contains words `or,not`
```

**Output**

2 -> as two words from find array are contained in text array values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array_intersect):

```
if (count(array_intersect($find, $text)) >= 1) {
    // both arrays have at least one common element
}
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/83723)

---

**UPDATE:** If you're trying to find how many elements in `$text` array contain any of the values (partial match or whole-word match) in `$find` array, you can use the following solution:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($find as $needle) {
    foreach ($text as $haystack) {
        if(strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) $counter++;
    }
}
echo $counter; // => 2
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/83727)

Comment: I want if array value contains `or,and ,not` not the whole word match

Comment: @Ace: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Could you post the expected output in the question?

Comment: @AmalMurali in the question text array has `jasvjasvor` as value it contains word `or` somewhere in the string. I want to verify that if it contains the words that are in $find array

Comment: @AmalMurali tnx. foreach will run many number of times. Will it affect speed or functioning in any way?

Comment: @Ace: The inner `foreach` loop will execute 9 times, which is the number of array elements in `$find` multiplied by number of array elements in `$text`. If `$text` had 5 elements, then the inner foreach loop will execute 15 times.

Comment: @AmalMurali was going to buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter=0;  
foreach($find as $txt){
 foreach($txt as $value){
        if (strstr($value, $txt)) {
        $counter++;
}
}
```

Comment: The code should be like http://codepad.viper-7.com/6UcMol. your code is working ok. but if there are lot of symbols and lot of texts it will run foreach a number of time. Is there an easy way?