# Check if arrays contain shared elements regardless of index

Tags: javascript, arrays, matching

I'd like to check if two arrays share elements regardless of order.

Given

```
array A: ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']

array B: ['how', 'are', 'hello']
```

Will return matches for 'hello', 'how', and 'are'

There seems to be something for PHP, `array_intersect()` ([Check if array contains elements having elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815091/check-if-array-contains-elements-having-elements-of-another-array)), but nothing for JavaScript.

I would use `in` if the values were in an object, but they are not:

```
if (key in obj) {

}
```

I could also do `array.sort()` to both arrays, but it's not guaranteed that both arrays will have same number of values. Therefore even if they are sorted, the compared indices would be off anyway.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to check if the same element is present in the other array.

```js
var arr1 = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'];
var arr2 = ['how', 'are', 'hello'];

var commonElements = arr1.filter(function(e) {
  return arr2.indexOf(e) > -1;
});

console.log(commonElements);
```

You can also define this function on Array prototype

```js
Array.prototype.intersection = function(arr) {
  return this.filter(function(e) {
    return arr.indexOf(e) > -1;
  });
};

var arr1 = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'],
  arr2 = ['how', 'are', 'hello'];

var commonElements = arr1.intersection(arr2);
console.log(commonElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering performance I'd convert one of the array to an object, and then check intersection by traversing the other.

```
var arr1 = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'];
var arr2 = ['how', 'are', 'hello'];
var set = {};
var intersect = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) 
    set[arr1[i]] = true;
for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
    if (set[arr2[i]]) intersect.push(arr2[i]);
```

But this method will ignore duplicate items in the arrays. And this may seem verbose compared to the filter and find solution. This may be helpful if you're doing intersection of large arrays.

Comment: `for...in` on an Array ?

Comment: @Kaiido you may use `for (..;..;..)` if you're more comfortable with that, but `for...in` can be used on arrays.

Comment: @Kaiido Well I'm not sure about older browsers. But most browsers won't do this if you didn't add any other non-numeric attribute to the array.

Comment: @Kaiido But I'll change my answer since it may seem annoying.

Answer (score 0):

In this approach, the first array is converted into a map, for fast lookup.

The second array is matched against the first.

The complexity is O(a) + O(b).

Pro: Elegance.

Con: Matching is continued after the overlap is detected.

```
function array_overlap(a, b) {
  const lookup = a.reduce((m, n) => (m[n]=true, m), {});
  const status = b.reduce((m, n) => (lookup[n] || m), false);
  return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 syntax:

```
var intersection = arr1.filter( e => arr2.includes( e ) )
```